# averagePowerForChannel working with iOSimulator but don't on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

In my small application for iOS 8.0 I'm measuring microphone's input level and if it's greater than -40 dB I'm changing the image in UIImageView and playing mp3-file. It works great in iOSimulator but doesn't work on iPad iOS 8.0. (microphone is accessible for app). What's the issue?
Thanks.

```
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

NSTimer *meterTimer;
AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
AVAudioPlayer *player;
NSString *audioFilePath; NSURL *pathAsURL;   // for audioplayer

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {   [super viewDidLoad];

meterTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3    // sets timer interrupt
target:self selector:@selector(timerArrived) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless],AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,nil];
NSError *error;
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSTemporaryDirectory()
            stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp.caf"]]  settings:settings error:&error];
[recorder prepareToRecord];
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorder record];
}

- (void)timerArrived    // called by timer
{   int intPower; float fValue;
    [recorder updateMeters];    // check input level
    fValue = [recorder averagePowerForChannel:0];
    intPower = roundf(fValue);
    if (intPower > -40)
{   _microphImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Microphone2.png"];
    audioFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aga" ofType:@"mp3"];
    pathAsURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:audioFilePath]; NSError *error;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pathAsURL error:&error];
    [player play];
}
else {_microphImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Microphone.png"];}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];} 
@end
```